# Include na tag <head> Djanto Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Eu tenho os seguintes arquivos:

`base.html`:

```
<!-- base.html -- -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title> 
        {% include "head.html" %} 
    </head>
    <body>
        Body
    </body>
</html>
```

`head.html`:

```
<!-- head.html -- -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

O meu problema é quando o navegador interpreta as paginas, o código do  `head.html` são colocados no `<body>` da pagina. Já tentei usar um block no `head` mas aconteceu o mesmo problema, como eu conseguiria resolver esse problema?

O navegador interpreta desta maneira:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        "&#65279;"
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        Body
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, o problema estava na codificação do arquivo *.HTML*, Abri o arquivo em um editor de texto, e o salvei como `UTF-8`, e corrigiu o *bug*.

O navegador estava gerando um carácter especial que era considerado texto, então jogava o código do *head*  dentro do `<body>`da página;